# Why getchar() doesn't work but getchar_unlocked() do outside main function while reading string character wise?

Tags: c, string, getchar

Here in read() function when I use **getchar()** it reads only one character. It breaks the loop even if the condition in **while()** is true but **getchar_unlocked()** reads characters until given condition fails
code is to calculate max value like:

```
input :
4
8-6+2+4+3-6+1
1+1+1+1
2+3+6+8-9
2+7+1-6

output : 
10 //(which is max value of 3rd string)
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline int read(int *value) {
    char c, c1 = '+';
    *value = 0;
    c = getchar_unlocked();
    while ((c >= '0'  && c <= '9') || c == '+' || c == '-') {
        if (c == '+' || c == '-') c1 = c;
        else *value = (c1=='+' ? *value + (c-'0') : *value - (c-'0'));
        c = getchar_unlocked();
    }
    return *value;
}

int main()
{
    int n, max=0, val;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char x = getchar();
    while(n--) {
        read(&val);
        max = val>max?val:max;
    }

    printf("%d", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only time when there is a difference between `getchar()` and `getchar_unlocked()` is in a multithreaded program. Otherwise, they behave the same.  Therefore, your diagnosis seems improbable and/or implausible. Please identify the platform (o/s and compiler) you're using.  Note that writing a function `read()` is treading on thin ice in a POSIX program.

Comment: Both `getchar` and `getchar_unlocked` return an `int`, not a `char`. (That is not your problem but it is good to get into the habit of using `int`.)

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: the function: `getchar()` (and its' relative: `getchar_unlocked()`) read every character in the input stream.  Including spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.  The posted code is trying to treat those non digit characters as digits.  This means the code fails.  You might want to make use of `#include <ctype.h>` and the facility `isdigit()`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the well known function name `read()`, as provided by the header file: `unistd.h`  should not be overlayed by some local function with the same name.

Comment: the posted code contains a logic error.  What happens if all the returned values from `read()` are less than 0?  To fix this, initialize `val` to `INT_MIN` which is defined in the `limits.h` header file

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired function
3. properly handles characters other than 0...9 and '+' and '-'
4. properly checks for I/O errors
5. is formatted for ease of readability and understanding
6. documents why each header file is included
7. uses function names that do not conflict with C library names
8. properly terminates the format string to `printf()` so data is immediately displayed on the terminal.
9. still contains a potential problem if the input does not contain enough lines to match the number on the first line.

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), getchar()
#include <limits.h>  // INT_MIN
#include <ctype.h>   // isdigit()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE


inline int myRead( void )
{
    int c;
    char  c1 = '+';

    int value = 0;

    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != c )
    {
        if (c == '+' || c == '-')
            c1 = (char)c;

        else if( isdigit( c ) )
            value = (c1=='+' ? value + (c-'0') : value - (c-'0'));
    }
    return value;
}


int main( void )
{
    int n;
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int val;

    if( 1 != scanf("%d", &n) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for number of following lines failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    while(n--)
    {
        val = myRead();
        max = val>max?val:max;
    }

    printf("%d\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```